# Pdfbox 2.0.0-RC1 print staple issu

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am currently using pdfbox 2.0.0-RC1 release for pdf printing.
But when I use printer staple options (using printer preferences) it staples the pdf on the wrong side.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(byteArrayInputStream);
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.setPrintService(lookupPrintService());
PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(pdDoc);
printJob.setPageable(pageable);
printJob.print();
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(byteArrayInputStream);PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
   printJob.setPrintService(lookupPrintService());
   PDFPageable pageable = new PDFPageable(pdDoc);
   printJob.setPageable(pageable);printJob.print();

Comment: @RiteshMathur: You can edit your question. If you want to provide code that is relevant to the question, please don't do that in the comments, but edit your question instead. It's much easier to read there.

Comment: The code seems to be OK. I wonder if it works with other applications? do also have a look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2930